# Error using stable_partiton

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to solve a topcoder problem where I have to remove all the vowels from a string unless the string contains only vowels. I am trying to partition the string using stable_partition and a function isVowel.
`

```
// {{{ VimCoder 0.3.6 <-----------------------------------------------------
// vim:filetype=cpp:foldmethod=marker:foldmarker={{{,}}}

#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// }}}

class VowelEncryptor
{
public:
    bool isVowel(char letter)
    {
        return (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'u');
    }
    vector <string> encrypt(vector <string> text)
    {
        int nElements = text.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
        {
            string::iterator bound = stable_partition(text[i].begin(), text[i].end(), isVowel);
            if (bound != text.end())
            {
                text[i].erase(text[i].begin(), bound);
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
};
```

But on compiling I am getting this error message:

```
(3 of 458): error: cannot convert ‘VowelEncryptor::isVowel’ from type ‘bool (VowelEncryptor::)(char)’ to type ‘bool (VowelEncryptor::*)(char)’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making `isVowel` static.

A pointer to a member function can't be used without an actual object instance to be called on, which `stable_partition` can't do without help. Either make the function `static` or use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Answer (score 2):

Your `isVowel` function is not in any way dependent on any state of a `VowelEncryptor` class object. It should be a free function, or a static member function. Incidentally, this should fix your error.